# Should I switch from learning the Violin to learn Piano Keyboard instead?

Tags: piano, violin, keyboard, beginner

I bought a violin over 2 years ago and yet I haven't learned anything since I couldn't get lessons. I was supposed to get some this summer but with the pandemic going on I couldn't. I really tried to learn the violin but no luck I can't find anything that will help me online and the violin requires precise hand movements and when I tune it, the strings keep going back to their original position and become off-tune again. No matter how much I try... I just can't, even though I really want to.

My friend said I should get a keyboard instead, **so should I? Will it be easier for me to learn it online?**

Comment: This would make an outstanding chatroom discussion, but not a good fit for the Q&A part of the site.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your personal preference is. Violin is much harder to start online as a beginner, and there's a chance of you developing a posture issue an in-person instructor might have caught, but as long as you're careful it's more than possible to learn it.

> I really tried to learn the violin but no luck I can't find anything
> that will help me online

If you're financially able, it's best to find a private instructor.

> The violin requires precise hand movements and when I tune it, the
> strings keep going back to their original position and become off-tune
> again.

Those hand movements will come to you with time and practice. Usually, all it takes to tune a violin is some gentle pressure into the scroll, but it could also be a technical issue. You might want to get that checked if it's not just a strength problem.

Comment: "Violin is much harder to start online as a beginner". Online piano lessons can be problematic as well. The teacher can miss something as the camera cannot show everything that a teacher can see at a "normal" piano lesson.

Comment: @andrewjohnsson online music lessons, in general, are harder than in-person lessons regardless of instrument, but violin is extra challenging because of how much of your tone and intonation depends on your posture.